# C# selectively turn off monitor

Tags: c#, controls, monitor, multiple-monitors

is there a way in C# to identify all monitors connected to the system and choose which ones to turn on, off or low power? The previous questions i found on SO just turn off all monitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDisplayMonitors?  Seems like once you get the handle then you can use PInvoke like it's used in the replies to the following question... [Turn on/off monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor)