# C# Turn off selected monitor

Tags: c#, dllimport

I'm wondering if someone could help me I have been trying to find a way of turning off specific monitors in a basic application, there are a couple of posts on here about turning off all monitors and this works fine. The only topic I can see if this one here:
[C# selectively turn off monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705019/c-sharp-selectively-turn-off-monitor)

This does explain how to go about doing this but I'm still learning and not really sure how to expand the example into whats needed.

Turn off all monitors:

```
public void MonitorOff(IntPtr handle)
    {
        SendMessage(handle, WmSyscommand, (IntPtr)ScMonitorpower, (IntPtr)MonitorShutoff);
    }

 private void MonitorOn()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseeventfMove, 0, 1, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        Thread.Sleep(40);
        mouse_event(MouseeventfMove, 0, -1, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
    }


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dx, Int32 dy, Int32 dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    private const int WmSyscommand = 0x0112;
    private const int ScMonitorpower = 0xF170;
    private const int MonitorShutoff = 2;
    private const int MouseeventfMove = 0x0001;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lpRect, MonitorEnumProc callback, int dwData);

    private delegate bool MonitorEnumProc(IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref Rect pRect, int dwData);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }
```

Count Monitors:

```
public void GetMonitors()
    {

        int monCount = 0;
        //Rect r = new Rect();
        MonitorEnumProc callback = (IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref Rect prect, int d) => ++monCount > 0;

        if (EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0))
           MessageBox.Show("You have " + monCount.ToString() + " monitors", "Windows Hook");
        else
           MessageBox.Show("An error occured while enumerating monitors");

    }
```

Is anyone able to enplane this or show me the right route to take?, Thank you.

Comment: Inside [`MonitorEnumProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145061(v=vs.85).aspx) callback `hdc` is monitor handle, use it with `MonitorOff()` method.

Comment: Thanks very much Sinatr, will give it a try!