# Turn monitor on/off

Tags: java, c#, bash

How can I make programmatically turn off, on a multi monitor system, the monitor which have nothing active on it, and turn back on when activity is detected, like mouse move?

Comment: Use System.Runtime.InteropServices to call kernel dll. [stackover flow discussion here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572441/sendmessage-sc-monitorpower-wont-turn-monitor-on-when-running-windows-8/14171736#14171736)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **you can't**.

Long answer: It is theoretically possible, but will require creating your own display driver and GUI library (maybe you can adapt standard one).