# How to turn monitors on and off in C# (multiple monitors)

Tags: c#, screen

I am writing a program in C# to turn off my monitors and I need a little help.
I have got code to detect how many monitors are connected and the form displays a list for each monitor.
I'm aware that windows does have some functions to turn off all monitors, but I'd like to turn on/off the selected monitor only.
I'm running Windows 10 using the latest C# API.

Anyone know of some places I could start?

Edit: I see some people have commented some pages below, however I tested the code and it does not work.

Comment: What is question exactly? _I press the F3 key and it shows a screen to enter a password_ - that you have, _to turn off the monitor after a delay of 30 seconds_ - what you need, right?

Comment: I tested this code [https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636982/2948684](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636982/2948684) - work fine on Windows 10

Comment: Yeah, turning off the monitor. But the code I've seen already only turns off one or all monitors. The one above just duplicates the password form. So strange... :\

Comment: Thanks for the links. :)