# How to turn off monitor power programmatically in windows 10 if power button is broken

Tags: java, c#, powershell, monitor

The power button on my second monitor is broken. I'm tired of manually unplugging the cable from the monitor. What do I want is to write a small app (Java, C#, or PowerShell script) that will turn the second monitor off and back on. I googled my problem and found a script that can put the monitor into sleep mode. But that's not exactly what I need.

Comment: Please show us what you already got and give as a name of your monitor, so we can help

Comment: I think it would be pretty difficult. But I found a link that might help: https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/18/pstip-how-to-switch-off-display-with-powershell/

Comment: `[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);`
`SendMessage(0xFFFF, 0x112, 0xF170, (int)state);`

Comment: Do you understand this code?

Comment: @Nicicalu I don't know what do you mean by monitor name, but it's LG monitor flatron l1752S

Comment: I couldn't figure what is first 3 params (SendMessage method) in code I gave

Comment: okay. it is a pretty hard task for a beginner. I wouldn't know how to do this either. Maybe you'll find some help in the internet or someone else comments here :/

Comment: Is your question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor  ? Please, see the answers to this question.

My own opinion: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be a trivial task. I'm almost sure you won't get it resolved because everything related to the power is usually managed by the operating system. Hence, you would need to interfere with the operating system at a fairly low-level. But the SendMessage is an API provided by the operating system for similar things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that you can't turn off the power source for your monitor programmatically if the monitor has two cables - one for PC and another for power.

Comment: Yes, that sounds plausible. Just buy a socket with the On/Off button :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) by Nirsoft.

You can use it, or develop a program to work with.

Once I used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` in `Java` to get the job done.

Comment: This just puts the monitor into a sleep mode.