# How to turn off monitor in c#

Tags: c#, windows-10

I am trying to turn off both monitors on my computer in c#. I am aware of using SendMessage (pretty much all I can find information about) to do that but it doesn't work and only shows the lock screen, not actually turning the monitors off. Is there any other way to to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shut down the computer from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-from-c-sharp)

Comment: I think it is a duplicated question. Please, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-from-c-sharp

Comment: Just look up SC_MONITORPOWER.  Lots of hits telling you how to do it is lots of languages.

Comment: This one turns the monitor off. You seem to be locking the monitor. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor/713504#713504

Comment: @alvaropaco this question is about turning off the monitor, that question is about turning of the computer. While the latter might achieve the former I wouldn't say they are the same

Comment: @RossBush That answer is the exact one that I have been trying and does not work.

Comment: @alvaropaco I do not want to turn off the computer

Comment: @Vincent did you read my question?

Comment: See this page:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor)

Comment: If WinAPI does not work, perhaps you can run [NirCmd monitor](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/monitor.html) or this NirSoft command via [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start): [How to turn off monitor from GUI and command-line on Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/turn-off-monitor.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn on/off monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor)