# How to turn on/ wake the screen with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, wakeup

I am struggling with this code for turning on the monitor. I have set in the Windows 10 control panel the display to turn off after 10 minutes, but I have one voice recognizing app written in VB and I need to wake the screen when I call the application via voice. So is there a code for waking the monitor trough **Visual Basic**? I searched a long time but I only find some Java code. Thanks and have a great day/night! :)

Comment: There's surely a way to do this via win32 api calls.

Comment: Found it after about 30 seconds: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11099/Turn-on-off-monitor

Comment: If you need me to convert it to vb for you, let me know.

Comment: Wow yeah I found that one and I was trying to convert it but I didn't succeed. I think that's on C right? If so I will need some help. :)

Comment: Please take a moment to read [Ask] and take the [Tour]  It will save you downvotes in the long run.

Comment: I converted it to vb.net (it was c#, actually) and it didn't work on windows10, investigating now ;).

Comment: Working on a solution, but I've got to go for now, so I'll come back when I can :).

Comment: Ok, no problem! Thanks. :)

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332649/how-do-i-wake-up-my-windows-monitors-once-turned-off-by-power-settings?rq=1) ? It was originally for Win XP but apparently worked on Vista... Maybe it'll do for Win10

Comment: I tried it but it does not work for Windows 10. I'm using Visual Basic Express 2010 btw. Thanks for the attention! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, so, with the guidance of [the article on codeproject](http://codeproject.com/Articles/11099/Turn-on-off-monitor), some of the answers given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor) and [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net), I've got something working. It could be cleaner, but I leave that up to you :). it is *your* project, after all ;).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Monitor
    Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Private Const SC_MONITORPOWER As Integer = &HF170
    Private Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
    Private Const INPUT_MOUSE As Integer = 0
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE As Integer = 1

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SendInput(<[In]()> ByVal nInput As UInt32,<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubtype:=UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamindex:=0)> ByVal pInputs() As INPUT, <[In]()> ByVal cbInput As Int32) As UInt32
    End Function

    Private Structure INPUT
        Public type As Integer
        Public dx As Integer
        Public dy As Integer
        Public mouseData As Integer
        Public dwFlags As Integer
        Public time As Integer
        Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
    End Structure


    Public Shared Sub Disable()
         SendMessage(New IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, New IntPtr(2))
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Enable()
        Dim input = New INPUT()

        input.type = INPUT_MOUSE
        input.dx = 1
        input.dy = 0
        input.mouseData = 0
        input.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE
        input.time = 0
        input.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero

        SendInput(1, {input}, 28)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! After about a mount I was trying to convert the Java and C to VB, trying to move the mouse and I succeed in moving the cursor but not waking up the screen! You did it in one hour! Now I will trim it out the code and implement it to my small Arduino voice dashboard application. THANK YOU SO MUCH! :) :) :)

Comment: No worries, the native windows API is almost always the answer ;). Sounds like a cool project, too. Maybe I'll be inspiredto wipe the dust off of my arduino and play around with it again :D.

Comment: You can do A LOT of things with an Arduino board and serial communication with VB. You can even control the board trough the Internet via VB.